# Tomcat is failing to connect to db with tomcat service but successfull with startup.bat

Tags: tomcat

I am facing an issue with tomcat.
I am using a conneciton pool for my application and it uses inbuilt authentication as true.

When i am running the tomcat with startup.bat, my application runs fine and its able to connect to the database.
But when I try to use tomcat as service and use tomcat8w.exe it gives me error and says its failed to login to the SQL server with ID "xxxx" . here the "xxxx" is not he id i have provided as my user id but its showing my machine name.

So when i am using startup.bat it taking my id correctly but when i am using tomcat8w.exe to start my tomcat it takes my /$ as user and then it says it failed.

Any idea my its taking machine name as user name and how can i fix it

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are using integrated security to connect to you SQL Server database? Make sure your connection string contains `User Id` and `Password` and not `trusted_connection` or `integrated security`.

OR you could change the windows user the tomcat service is running under. Open services on windows and open the properties for your tomcat service. You can change the windows user in the second panel `Log On`. Try to set the account to the user you are logged in as.

Ideally you would choose a windows user which has access to the Database but not much else. And then use `integrated security` so you don't need to store plain text passwords in your connection string.

Comment: thanks for the respnse but its running fine when i run the tomcat8.5 using startup.bat but the same tomcat when i run from eclipse its gives error "WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory]"